# get number of users of different type

Tags: mysql

I got table `Users` with field `type = enum('admin', 'editor', 'regular')`.

how can i get number of admins, editors and regular users in one query?

My solution was in 3 queries like: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE type='admin'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using [group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count ,type FROM users  group by type
```